# The best way for search page on some field in asp .net core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a search form that has some different fields a user can search on. fields and results are in the same page, what is the best way for that?
for example results can be in seprate partial view, or do that with ajax or create a ne w model that has search model and results in it .

which way is the best way in asp .net core?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say which one is the best practice, it is based on your specific needs.

If you don't want to refresh the whole page, you can use ajax call the filter result and replace the orignal one. On the other hand, if you don't want to write any scripts, you can just  submit the search form then return the view with the filter model.